# Is there a option to import downloaded APIs from WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2

I have downloaded one API (as api.zip file), which I created in WSO2 API Manager from the Administation console. Is there a way to import this API in different WSO2 instance?

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Data of a published API from APIPublisher stored in three places.

1. In file-system [as a synapse config API element]
2. In database level

   -- as registry data [stored API static meta-data]

   -- as directly stored data in APIM db [stored API runtime data]

I believe you have downloaded the API element from Metadata-> List-> APIs in management console,which is stored in registry space.To restore a created API in another wso2 AM instance,this downloaded API element is not sufficient.

If you want to backup API data from one APIManager instance and restore in another instance,what you have to do is backup both above file-system and database specific data and restore.Other than that,currently there's no direct download and upload mechanism to do API backup and restoring process in WSO2 APIManager.

Thanks;